# Postgresql select distinct Column A based on certain conditions on Column B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with data:

```sql
+--------+---------+
| userid | status  |
+--------+---------+
| user_1 | success |
| user_2 | fail    |
| user_2 | success |
| user_3 | fail    |
| user_3 | fail    |
+--------+---------+
```

I would like my query output to be distinct on `userid` but with condition that between `fail` and `success` values in `status` column. I would like to choose `success` instead (if both `fail` as in `user_3`, choose `fail` then). The table below shows the output that I would like to have as my result:

```sql
+--------+---------+
| userid | status  |
+--------+---------+
| user_1 | success |
| user_2 | success |
| user_3 | fail    |
+--------+---------+
```

Any efficient query would be nice as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pretty efficient way to get the results you need.

```
SELECT userid, MAX(status)
FROM table1
GROUP BY userid
```

The MAX() function will work for strings as well.
Since, "success" > "fail",
if a userid has 1 row of "success" and 1 row of "fail", the maximum value is "success"

Answer (score 4):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT ON`, which provides a simple and readable method to get the rows unique on `userid`. The `ORDER BY` ensures that `status = 'success'` is sorted before `'fail'`, and hence `'success'`is selected if present:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid) userid,
                   status
FROM my_table
ORDER BY userid,
         status DESC;
```

Note: An multicolumn index on `(status, userid)` may help performance. Also, in some cases a query using `GROUP BY` (see the answer from Terence) may be faster than the one using `DISTINCT`.

---

> `SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] )` keeps only the first row
> of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. ...
> The `DISTINCT ON` expression(s) must match the leftmost `ORDER BY`
> expression(s). The `ORDER BY` clause will normally contain additional
> expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within
> each `DISTINCT ON` group.

(From [`SELECT DISTINCT` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) )

Comment: Didn't know this one. It is not standard SQL but as it works on postgresql it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

First select status is success userid.

```
select distinct  userid,status from yourtable where status='success'
```

Second select userid not contain success status.

```
select distinct  userid,status from yourtable where 
userid not in(select distinct userid from yourtable where status='success')
```

Then union.

```
select distinct  userid,status from yourtable where status='success'
union
select distinct  userid,status from yourtable where 
userid not in(select distinct userid from yourtable where status='success')
```